# Same Web Service client for both Java and .Net

Tags: web-services

I have a web service written in java. having following methods

**Java Service Name: Test Service**

Hosted at : http://x.x.x.x:8080/TestService

```
method1(String arg1):String

method1(String arg1, String arg2):Boolean
```

where as I have same service written in .Net having only one method

**.NET Service Name: Test Service**

Hosted at : http://x.x.x.x:/TestService

```
method1(string arg1):string
```

Now I have a web service client in .NET generated from wsdl of Java Webservice and i am calling only method1(string arg1):string

What if I change the service URL in client program from http://x.x.x.x:8080/TestService (Java Service) to http://x.x.x.x/TestService (.NET Service), will it work after this change or not?

Answer (score 1):

As long as both services share the same namespace, this should work.

Search for `namespace` in the `binding` elements of the WSDL.